# REGEX mysql for comma separated values

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, select, find-in-set

I have a mysql query in java like

```
public static BusObjectIterator<con.PROJECT_EMP> GetEmpObjectsforOrgandMultipleCategory(String ORG, String CATEGORY)
    {
String query=select * from PROJECT_EMP where org = :ORG and category=:CATEGORY;
.....
return ...
}
```

Here the param ORG will have single value like xyz and CATEGORY String may have multiple values like  Cat1,Cat2 etc..,
So dynamically i would like to frame query using REGEX to replace the comma separated string values like

```
select * from PROJECT_EMP where org = 'xyz' and category in ('Cat1','Cat2');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**FIND_IN_SET()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function instead of `RegEx`

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM PROJECT_EMP WHERE org = :ORG AND FIND_IN_SET(category,:CATEGORY);
```